# Spring not catch all object of my rest petition

Tags: java, spring, rest

My method is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/asignar", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseViewEntity<ResultadoJSON> asignar(
            @RequestParam(required = true, value = "usuario") String usuario,           
            @RequestParam(required = true, value = "clienteId") Long clienteId,         
            ListaLotes lotes) {
....
}
```

Object ListaLotes

```
public class ListaLotes {   
    private List<LoteForm> lotes;
}
```

Object LoteForm

```
public class LoteForm {
    private Long loteId;
    private Long cantidad;
}
```

But when i realize the petition throught PostMan, the object "lotes" its always null

PETITION REST

[Rest Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R98j0.png)

[Rest body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7ohh.png)

What I should do for it works ? I can't modify my Java code its part of an API. Only can modify de REST Petition

Comment: remove`headers = "Accept=application/json"`,get can not send data by request body.use post

Comment: What is `null`? Also, in your `@RequestMapping`, your path is `/asign`, while in your screenshot you're querying `/asignar`.

Comment: you should use @RequestBody

Comment: the object lotes its always null, the  path its asignar was an error when i typed de answer

Comment: You should change the method to RequestMethod.POST. Null body is because of GET, your body will be empty. Also add an @RequestBody on lotes parameter

Answer (score 1):

As has already been commented, if you want to transfer data to your controller, you need to use the `POST` method and mark the paramter as `@RequestBody`.

```
// or @PostMapping
@RequestMapping(value = "/asignar", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseViewEntity<ResultadoJSON> asignar(
            @RequestParam(required = true, value = "usuario") String usuario,           
            @RequestParam(required = true, value = "clienteId") Long clienteId,         
            @RequestBody ListaLotes lotes) {
....
}
```